# How to list all "A" column values if "D" column equals a specific value

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I have a spreadsheet that looks like this on Google Drive:
[image]

Further down the page, I do a count of everyone who matches a specific date (which is dynamically updated), and I want to LIST out the names of all the people registered for that date.

[image]

So, basically, the formula scans the entire D column, checking to see if any values match C127, and if so, it makes a list of the A values of those matching columns, ideally comma separated, like "Name 1, Name 2, Name 3" - there should be 6 names in total.

Comment: why should be 6 names in total? Could you please post an example which match your description? please note that solution could be different in Excel and Google spreadsheet, only Excel is on-topic here, if you're happy to get a solution in Excel then please revmove google-spreadsheet tag.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshots, I assumed you are looking for the solution in Google Sheets rather than Excel (per Máté's comment).

One solution is to use [`FILTER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) and [`JOIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en) functions. In cell E127, enter:

```
=JOIN(", ", FILTER(A:A,D:D=C127))
```

This will give you the string of matching names in a single cell.

[image]